# What healing items that recharge are available in DDO?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-online

In DDO, there's a number of ways of healing yourself. You can have a healer in the party (either a player or hireling), you can use wands or scrolls if your Use Magic Device is high enough, and you can use potions. However, there's also some items that have healing magic on them that recharges for multiple uses between resting (such as the *Curative Cloak* from the Redemption quest, and the *Bracers of Assistance* from the Cannith Crystal quest).

These are the only two items of this sort I've found anywhere. Are there any others (preferably F2P) that I can get as quest rewards? Basically, I want healing items with infinite recharges but limited uses per day. This is as a supplement to hirelings and other party members.

(I'm a level 6 Two-handed Fighter)

Comment: For soloing or small parties a healing hireling is the most cost effective way to get healing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many such items in the game.  Here is a list of most of the "active" curative items in no particular order:

- The [Bracers of Assistance](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Bracers_of_Assistance) provide an `Aid` clicky, which grants temporary hit points but is not clasified as a "cure" or "heal" item.
- The [Curative Cloak](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Curative_Cloak) grants 1 charge of `Cure Light Wounds` per rest.
- The [Eternal Wand of Cure Minor Wounds](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Eternal_Wand_of_Cure_Minor_Wounds) grants 50 charges of `Cure Minor Wounds`, which is an effect that will restore 1d2 hit points per charge.  This is an "Eternal" wand that recharges about 1 charge every 7 seconds when not being used.
- The [Vestments of Light](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Vestments_of_Light) grants 3 charges of `Cure Light Wounds` per rest.
- The [Battle Coin](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Battle_Coin) grants 3 charges of `Heal Moderate Wounds` per day, but can only be used on self.
- The [Bottomless Flask of Rum](http://ddowiki.com/page/Bottomless_Flask_of_Rum) available from the "Crystal Cove" event will, depending on what tier you take it to, grant a reasonable amount of healing once every 5 to 10 minutes.
- The [Epic Hammer of Life](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Epic_Hammer_of_Life) will grant 3 charges of `Heal, Mass` and will recharge at a rate of 1/day.
- The [Levik's Defender](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Levik%27s_Defender)'s `Healer's Bounty` has the chance to cast `Heal` on the user every time (s)he is attacked.

There are also "Passive" type items that do not require you to click on anything or get hit.  You simply have to have them equipped.  The nice things about these items is that if the item procs while you are incapacitated, it is "like" having the diehard feat and you will automatically stabilize.

- [(Lesser) Regeneration](http://ddowiki.com/page/Regeneration) items (1 HP every minute)

  - [Mantle of the Worldshaper](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Mantle_of_the_Worldshaper)
  - [Ring of Troll's Regeneration](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Ring_of_Troll%27s_Regeneration)
  - [Dampened Greatclub of the Scrag](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Dampened_Greatclub_of_the_Scrag)
  - [Greatclub of the Scrag](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Greatclub_of_the_Scrag)
  - [Battered Marketplace Shield](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Battered_Marketplace_Shield)
  - [Shield of the Azure Valkyrie](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Shield_of_the_Azure_Valkyrie)
  - Level 15 and 16 [Firebreak](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Firebreak)
  - Can also be crafted using Cannith Crafting with 80 levels in the "Divine" school.
  - Can also be crafted as a [first tier effect](http://ddowiki.com/page/Altar_of_Invasion_-_Manufactured_Ingredient_Recipes#OM) on [Greensteel Accessories](http://ddowiki.com/page/Green_Steel_Accessory)(NOT weapons)
- [Improved Regeneration](http://ddowiki.com/page/Regeneration#Improved_Regeneration) items (1 HP every 30 seconds)

  - Level 17 and 22 [Firebreak](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Firebreak)
  - Can also be crafted as a [second tier effect](http://ddowiki.com/page/Altar_of_Subjugation_-_Manufactured_Ingredient_Recipes#OM) on [Greensteel Accessories](http://ddowiki.com/page/Green_Steel_Accessory) (NOT weapons)
- [Greater Regeneration](http://ddowiki.com/page/Regeneration#Greater_Regeneration) items (2 HP every 30 seconds)

  - Level 23 and 24 [Firebreak](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Firebreak)
  - [Epic Greatclub of the Scrag](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Epic_Greatclub_of_the_Scrag)
  - One of the versions of [Belashyrra's Cleansed Scepter](http://ddowiki.com/page/Item:Belashyrra%27s_Cleansed_Scepter)
  - Can be crafted as a [third tier effect](http://ddowiki.com/page/Altar_of_Devastation_-_Manufactured_Ingredient_Recipes#OM) on [Greensteel Accessories](http://ddowiki.com/page/Green_Steel_Accessory) (NOT weapons)

Comment: Note that to get certain items as loot rewards you need to switch *off* the 'class specific rewards' setting in your game.